# pass multiple parameters from main to a class

Tags: python, oop

so I basically have this class:

```
class Cycle():

         def __init__(something in here):
                 self.id = id
                 self.name = name
                 self.lname = lname
```

and I have my main:

```
config = {
          "id":measurment[0]["id"],
          "name":measurment[0]["name"]
          "lname":measurment[0]["lname"]
}
cycle = Cycle()
```

what I want to do is basically how can I pass multiple parameters to the Cycle class?

to look like this:

```
cycle = Cycle(config["id"],config["name"],config["lname"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack into keyword arguments:

```
cycle = Cycle(**config)
```

```
class Cycle():

         def __init__(self, id, name, lname):
                 self.id = id
                 self.name = name
                 self.lname = lname
```

Comment: You also need `self` as the first argument to `__init__`.